# How do I pass rows from HTML form to PHP?

Tags: php, html

I'm written a PHP program to display a tab delimited file. The purpose of this is to allow the user to views the rows and select which ones they want by checking the checkbox given in the row for each record. After they hit submit I have a PHP program to display the values, but the problem is only the last row's ID is being passed. However, when the user hits the SUBMIT button I can see all the values for the rows checked:

```
   process_form.php?download=5108&download=5110&download=5114
```

How should I parse this in process_form.php? I've done a var_dump of $_POST and also
$_REQUEST but it only shows the last value which is 5114. I kind of understand the problem, most of the time in forms programmers only get one value per input field, but what happens when there are many records? It doesn't seem they should all have their own unique 'name'.

```
<td align=center><input type="checkbox" name="download" value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>"></td>
```

I'm doing something wrong here, but I'm not sure what. Is there a way to pass an array (I'm guessing) of IDs? Or should I be looking at parsing the URL of ?download=5108&download=5110&download=5114 because it has all the values I need there? If so, how do I do that? Thanks!

Comment: rename your inputs to download[], this will create an array of values instead

Comment: Add `[]` to `download`

Comment: eh.... i should delete my comment. too many duplicates.... should i?

Comment: Consider using method="post" in your form. There are no reason to show values of download in the url. And then just get the array with $arr = $_POST['download']; And there is a limit in the length of characters in an url... Consider this after adding brackets as waygood said of course! :-)

Comment: Waygood, put your comment as an answer and OP could approve it :-)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld: If he's changing something on the server, he should use POST server, he should use POST. If not, he should use GET. It's not a question of "it shouldn't be visible", it's a question of what you do with the information, GET it, or POST it.

Comment: Edward, is this solved? If so, please rollback the edits containing your solution, and add them to the page as an answer. This helps keep questions and answers separate (useful for the data API) and it may even earn you some answer reputation. Thanks `:)`.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha - yes that's true! :-) I was just trying to explain the consequence of using get instead of post.

Comment: @halfer, thanks, I followed your suggestion and posted the solution. (I'm still learning how to use stackoverflow)

Comment: That's great, thanks. You can either tick @lopisan's answer if it helped you, or you are entirely free to tick your own, if you solved it yourself. +1

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

```
<td align=center><input type="checkbox" name="download[]" value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>"></td>
```

Notice that download is now download[], thus creating an array to be passed to the PHP program to process the form.

Then using this demo PHP code I was able to get access to the array:

```
$my_array = ($_REQUEST["download"]);
print_r($my_array);
echo "<P>";
foreach ($my_array as $value)
{
    echo $value . "<BR>";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd rather use your `rowID` to identify the name of `<input>` instead of the value.

```
<td align=center><input type="checkbox" name="download_<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>" value="1"></td>
```

Then you can process your request array like:

```
foreach( $_REQUEST as $key => $value ) {
  if( preg_match('/^download_([0-9]+)$/', $key, $reg ) {
    $rowId = $reg[1];  // Your row ID
    $isChecked = $value;  // State of checkbox 
  }
}
```

The row ID is parsed from variable name using regexp.

**EDIT:**
As mentioned in comments, this is not the simplest way to read an array of checkboxes. The simpliest is to name checkboxes `download[]` and parse this array in PHP then. 
However, this is more universal, for example when you need to get array of input texts instead of checkboxes.

Comment: This seems to complicate things a LOT? Why not just grab the array with $_POST['download'] and iterate though the array?

Comment: You're right that it's maybe overkill for this simple task, but i'm used to do that this way even for checkboxes - i use this approach for arrays of textboxes where it's necessary. I'll edit the answer to say it's not the simpliest solution

Comment: Ok, but I really don't get it. When would your solution be benefitial?

Comment: This might not be the simplest approach, but it is perfectly fine, and certainly offers something for the OP to learn from - upvoting.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld: E.g. I have list of text inputs, each having unique Id. I need to get values in pairs: Id => value. When I use the name[] approach I just get list of values, not Id => value pairs.

Comment: @lopisan - ok that makes sense! But couldn't you just use do like this: download[<?php echo $row['ID']] ?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld - yes, it could be used. It's a good point.